# In a pinch, stuck in a simple onclick text cycle

Tags: javascript, html

For a project, I'm trying to highlight the logical fallacy of circular reasoning and have precious few lines of code later to be inserted into a separate webpage.

I am trying to create a simple process of clicking the displayed text to switch back and forth between the two questions. I've tried buttons and it only complicates and make no progress. Half a day gone, still banging my head on desk, as the phrase goes.

I read elsewhere that creating a var tracker facilitates, though I see it only for images, rather than displayed text. It feels like approaching my wits end, but I lack the time to walk away and try again.

This is my code thus far:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

<script>

function change() {
    var paragraph = document.getElementById("whytrust");
    paragraph.innerHTML="I am trustworthy, but how can you be sure?";
    }

</script>

</head>

<body>

<p id="whytrust" onclick="change();">You can trust me, but how can you be sure?</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like it will switch just one time. Is that the result you're getting?

Comment: Indeed so, it switches the one time, and I am remain at a loss as to have clicks toggle between the questions back and forth, after many hours of getting nowhere :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some place to hold the old message so you can put it back again after you toggle the contents.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

<script>

var newMsg = "I am trustworthy, but how can you be sure?";

function change() {
    var paragraph = document.getElementById("whytrust");
    var oldMsg = paragraph.innerHTML;
    paragraph.innerHTML = newMsg;
    newMsg = oldMsg;
    }

</script>

</head>

<body>

<p id="whytrust" onclick="change();">You can trust me, but how can you be sure?</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly! I wasn't sure how complicated it needed to be for a one to one cycle text display, and this demonstrates how slim it can be. I didn't know there was a property of oldMsg, but do see how dictating the code to accept a set of statements results in the functioning display.

Answer (score 0):

This a quick and dirty implementation of what you want. I added a `data-textindex` attribute to the html element. There I stored an index for the currently shown text. In the javascript I check the current value, update `data-textindex` and replace it with new text.

```js
function change() {
    let paragraph = document.getElementById("whytrust");
    let currentlyshown = paragraph.getAttribute('data-textindex');    
    if(currentlyshown == 0){
      paragraph.innerText="I am trustworthy, but how can you be sure?";
      paragraph.setAttribute('data-textindex', '1');
    }else if(currentlyshown == 1){
      paragraph.innerText="You can trust me, but how can you be sure?";
      paragraph.setAttribute('data-textindex', '0');
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="whytrust" data-textindex="0" onclick="change();">You can trust me, but how can you be sure?</p>
```

*On a sidenote: You can improve this code a lot. Like storing your text in a json-object. Or maybe using the ternary operator if you are 100% sure there will always be 2 choices. maybe give the function some arguments so you can apply it in a more general scenario.*

Comment: That is exactly what I was striving for, I shower you with utmost gratitude! ...I see where the problem was, of not attributing properties to be called upon within the page.. will need to study this much more, as there are plans for apps and websites emphasizing a use of the Socratic Method. Again, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try tracking some sort of 'state' for your paragraph -- be it on/off, active/inactive...

Each time the `change()` function gets called, it doesn't remember what the paragraph was or was supposed to be.  So, by setting a state of some sort (in my example a data-state attribute assigned to the paragraph element) the code can know how to behave.

```js
function change() {
    var paragraph = document.getElementById("whytrust");
    var output = '';
    
    // data-* can be anything, but handy for referencing things
    var state = paragraph.getAttribute('data-state');
    // check if data-state even exists
    if( !state ){
      // set it to the default/original state
      paragraph.setAttribute('data-state', 'inactive');
      state = 'inactive';
    }
    
    // toggle the state
    // and assign the new text
    if( state === 'inactive' ){
      paragraph.setAttribute('data-state', 'active' );
      output = "I am trustworthy, but how can you be sure?";
    }else{
      paragraph.setAttribute('data-state', 'inactive');
      output = "You can trust me, but how can you be sure?";
    }
    
    paragraph.innerHTML = output;
    
}
```

```html
<p id="whytrust" onclick="change();">You can trust me, but how can you be sure?</p>
```

Another option, without tracking state could be hiding and showing the paragraph you want displayed.  You don't really need to track state or save the alternating text...

```js
// get the elements from the DOM that you want to hide/show
// you can get tricky and add alternative ways to track
// the paragraph elements, but this works nice for a demo
const whytrust = document.getElementById('whytrust'),
      answer   = document.getElementById('whytrust-answer');

function change( element ){
  
  // the element parameter being passed is the paragraph tag
  // that is present/visible
  if( element.id === 'whytrust' ){
    answer.className = ''; // clear the .hide class
    whytrust.className = 'hide'; // add the .hide class
  }else{
    whytrust.className = ''; // clear the .hide class
    answer.className = 'hide'; // add the .hide class
  }

}
```

```css
.hide{ display: none; }
```

```html
<p id="whytrust" onclick="change(this);">I am trustworthy, but how can you be sure?"</p>
<p id="whytrust-answer" class="hide" onclick="change(this);">You can trust me, but how can you be sure?</p>
```

What I like about this solution is that it keeps the content in the HTML and the JavaScript just worries about what to hide/show.

Comment: Many thanks! I see that now, with its delegation of control, where as I was only addressing a one way statement without a path of return, which was the initial problem. There is much yet I need to learn ^^;